# How to create name tag for input tag without any id or class by javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am working with a form:

```
<div class="directions_holder">
                    <h4><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Get Direction</h4>
                    <p>Enter your location</p>
                    <form action="" align="right" onsubmit="calcRoute('routeStart615d1caf4ca70', '10.809556085818913', '106.62590956389425', 'map_canvas615d1caf4ca6f');
                                        return false;">
                        <input type="text" id="routeStart615d1caf4ca70" value="" placeholder="Your Location" style="margin-top:3px"><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Get Direction" class="button" onclick="calcRoute('routeStart615d1caf4ca70', '10.809556085818913', '106.62590956389425', 'map_canvas615d1caf4ca6f');
                                            return false;">
                    </form>
                </div>
```

And I want to add a name tag name="autocomplete_address" to this input to get the Autocomplete Address Plugin to work but I do not know how to find the input in javascript because this input's id always changed everytime I refresh the page so I do not know how to select it to add the name tag to it.

```
<input type="text" id="routeStart615d1caf4ca70" value="" placeholder="Your Location" style="margin-top:3px"><br><br>
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't use id as you selector maybe you can try something `DISTINCT` like placeholder selector so you can code like this

```
var elm = document.querySelectorAll('[placeholder="Your Location"]')[0];
elm.setAttribute("name","autocomplete_address");

//Alert current name
alert(elm.getAttribute("name"));
```

Or you can change value of `querySelectorAll()` with other attribute that suite you

Comment: It worked, you are my hero. Thank you so much!
I have another question, can I use 2 id in 1 <input> tag? The original id of the input start with routeStart and random number behind it, so that I cannot select this input, what if I add another ID for this input, is it work?

Comment: @sairy no, an element can not have more than one ID. If you set a new one, it will overwrite the old one.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried to replace the name by the id, when the id "autocomplete_address" replaced the input routeStart id, the Get Route of map is not work for test. But your code is work great, and now I know how to select a element without id and class. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector('input[type=text]')
will get the first input field on the page.

select the form first if you have more than one.

Comment: I have 2 forms with a lot of input feild, and the one I need help is the first one, I do not know how to select the form first because the form does not have any class or id, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this you want**

Remember one thing name is an attribute not a tag..

```
let form = document.getElementById("form");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "autocomplete_address");
    form.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried and got this error:
Uncaught TypeError: form is null

Comment: set the id of form is form like ```id="form"```

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery you can simply do this

```
$('.directions_holder input[type="text"]').attr('name','autocomplete_address');
```

Comment: I tried your code and got this error:
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: You need to add JQuery in your project